# Quantum Geometric Tensor and Berry Connection

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-geometry, quantum-information, quantum-states, coherent-states

The Quantum Geometric Tensor is given by
$$
\begin{split}
Q_{\mu\nu}=\langle\partial_{\mu}\psi|\partial_{\nu}\psi\rangle-\langle\partial_{\mu}\psi|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\partial_{\nu}\psi\rangle
\end{split}
$$
I wanted to confirm whether for the $SU(2)$ coherent state
$$
\begin{split}
|z\rangle=\frac{1}{(1+|z|^2)^j}\sum_{m=-j}^{m=j}\sqrt{\frac{2j!}{(j+m)!(j-m)!}}z^{j+m}|j,m\rangle
\end{split}
$$
The Berry curvature $(F)$ and connection $(A)$ are the following
$$
\begin{split}
F=i\frac{dz\wedge d\bar{z}}{(1+|z|^2)^2}~~~~~~
A=i\frac{\bar{z} dz}{(1+|z|^2)}
\end{split}
$$
I have figured out that the symmetric part viz $Q_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$ is the metric. But I don't see that how the exterior derivative of the Berry connection $A=i\langle\psi|d\psi\rangle$ is proportional to the anti-symmetric part $Q_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}$. In other words, I wanted to know that the for Kahler manifolds, whether the Berry curvature is proportional to the Kahler two form $Q_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}$.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I have reframed my question

Answer (score 1):

The quantum metric and Berry curvature are the symmetric and antisymmetric parts of Q, respectively. These are the same as the real and imaginary parts of Q, respectively again, because

$\langle \alpha | \beta \rangle = \langle \beta | \alpha \rangle^*.$

See this paper for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.01258.pdf

Comment: One of my problem is that I calculated the metric in the link posted in the question as (Here).  But I didn't had to take the real part of it.